# How to bind static resource from dictionary in android colors.xml

Tags: android, xaml, binding, maui, staticresource

I'm using .NET Maui and I defined a static resource in Colors.xaml file, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"   
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
   <Color x:Key="Primary">#47D1C1</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I want to bind it in colors.xml file defined for Android platform.
How can I do it? Here is the Android colors.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="colorPrimary"> here I want to bind Primary resource </color>
   <color name="colorPrimaryDark">??</color>
   <color name="colorAccent">??</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: It is XML file. XML...

Answer (score 0):

They are two different xml files for the different platforms. They can not bind the data from each other. If you want to [Theme an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming) you can use the ResourceDictionary.